# module 'search.views' has no attribute 'search'

Tags: python, django, wagtail

I'm using the wagtail cms to do a search. I'm using the default search in the /search folder. When I preform a search I get the following exception thrown at me.

AttributeError at /search/
module 'search.views' has no attribute 'search'

This is my views.py

```
    from django.core.paginator import EmptyPage, PageNotAnInteger, Paginator
from django.shortcuts import render

from wagtail.core.models import Page
from wagtail.search.models import Query


def search(request):
    search_query = request.GET.get('query', None)
    page = request.GET.get('page', 1)

    # Search
    if search_query:
        search_results = Page.objects.live().search(search_query)
        query = Query.get(search_query)

        # Record hit
        query.add_hit()
    else:
        search_results = Page.objects.none()

    # Pagination
    paginator = Paginator(search_results, 10)
    try:
        search_results = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        search_results = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        search_results = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

    return render(request, 'search/search.html', {
        'search_query': search_query,
        'search_results': search_results,
    })
```

This is my template/search/search.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load static wagtailcore_tags %}

{% block body_class %}template-searchresults{% endblock %}

{% block title %}Search{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <h1>Search</h1>

    <form action="{% url 'search' %}" method="get">
        <input type="text" name="query"{% if search_query %} value="{{ search_query }}"{% endif %}>
        <input type="submit" value="Search" class="button">
    </form>

    {% if search_results %}
        <ul>
            {% for result in search_results %}
                <li>
                    <h4><a href="{% pageurl result %}">{{ result }}</a></h4>
                    {% if result.search_description %}
                        {{ result.search_description }}
                    {% endif %}
                </li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>

        {% if search_results.has_previous %}
            <a href="{% url 'search' %}?query={{ search_query|urlencode }}&amp;page={{ search_results.previous_page_number }}">Previous</a>
        {% endif %}

        {% if search_results.has_next %}
            <a href="{% url 'search' %}?query={{ search_query|urlencode }}&amp;page={{ search_results.next_page_number }}">Next</a>
        {% endif %}
    {% elif search_query %}
        No results found
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %
```

}

I'm getting the following error when I preform a search

AttributeError at /search/
module 'search.views' has no attribute 'search'

URLS.py

```
from search import views as search_views

urlpatterns = [
url(r'^django-admin/', admin.site.urls),

url(r'^admin/', include(wagtailadmin_urls)),
url(r'^documents/', include(wagtaildocs_urls)),

url(r'^search/$', search_views.search, name='search'),

url(r'sitemap.xml', sitemap),

url(r'^wagtail-transfer/', include(wagtailtransfer_urls)),
```

]

Directory Structure

[image]

Comment: can you share your urls.py?

Comment: @mursalin Yes I have shared it now

Comment: I think you have another package installed named ```search```, try relative import. if you share your directory structure I can suggest more accurately.

Comment: @mursalin Thanks, I've added that. I'm not very familiar with Python/Django

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any error. What I'm assuming you have a django package by the same name 'search' installed. So I think changing your app name would resolve your problem.
On the other hand you can separate app urls from main urls and use relative import.
To do that you have to do

1. create a file named `urls.py` in your `search` app.

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views as search_view

urlpatterns = [
    path('', search_views.search, name='search')
]
```

2. include `urls.py`(form search) in your main `urls.py`

```
#from search import views as search_views

urlpatterns = [
url(r'^django-admin/', admin.site.urls),

url(r'^admin/', include(wagtailadmin_urls)),
url(r'^documents/', include(wagtaildocs_urls)),

url(r'^search/', include('search.urls')),

url(r'sitemap.xml', sitemap),

url(r'^wagtail-transfer/', include(wagtailtransfer_urls)),
]
```